# Delimiting a series of txt's and putting it into a csv or database

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, etl

I am convinced someone will know how to tackle this problem. I have a pet project where I am trying to build a database from several txt's per the below. Records are split by every 6th row which is blank. Field's are split by consecutive spaces and the end of the five rows making a record. Some field do have spaces.

I have tried DataStage and SPSS - but cant quiet seem to get the result. I have also tried Altova Mapforce which got me close. My selected database would probably be MySQL (given this is a project for my spare time)

```
SUNCOR ET AL MEDHAT 9-17-15-4        0416613   ALBERTA CROWN        753.3M                          
100/09-17-015-04W4/00  S  543.4M  W  167.6M    MEDICINE HAT         656.8M                        
DEV (NC)                             MEDICINE HAT                   FISH SCALE ZONE                 
VERTICAL                             NEW       PRODUCTION           GAS                             
SUNCOR ENERGY INC.                                                  09-17-015-04W4                  

CVE HOUSE 3-23-83-17                 0416614   ALBERTA CROWN        536.17M                         
1AB/03-23-083-17W4/00  N  281.3M  E  686.8M    BONNYVILLE           283.7M                       
OV (C)                               HOUSE                          MCMURRAY FM                     
VERTICAL                             NEW       OIL SAND EVALUATION  CRUDE BITUMEN                   
CENOVUS ENERGY INC.                                                 03-23-083-17W4                  

CVE GRANOR 11-27-82-18               0416615   ALBERTA CROWN        554.69M                         
1AA/11-27-082-18W4/00  S  756.7M  E  677.6M    BONNYVILLE           409.2M                        
OV (C)                               GRANOR                         GROSMONT FM                     
VERTICAL                             NEW       OIL SAND EVALUATION  CRUDE BITUMEN                   
CENOVUS ENERGY INC.                                                 11-27-082-18W4                  

SUNCOR ET AL MEDHAT 4-17-15-4        0416616   ALBERTA CROWN        750.9M                          
100/04-17-015-04W4/00  N  320.1M  E  317.1M    MEDICINE HAT         646.4M                        
DEV (NC)                             MEDICINE HAT                   FISH SCALE ZONE                 
VERTICAL                             NEW       PRODUCTION           GAS                             
SUNCOR ENERGY INC. 

                                             04-17-015-04W4
```

Some fields do include single spaces but never several consecutive spaces.

[image: this image should clarify fields and records]

Comment: This looks like a pretty structured format. `awk` would be good, or just do it in python. Once you've got it in a csv you can load it easily into mysql with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: From your sample each line appears to contain fixed length fields. Is that the case, can you just use substr() or unpack() on each line? I agree though w/beerbajay, convert to csv if the file is large. Just insert record by record if not. Use python, perl, whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Windows, I have reworked the awk and sed stuff into something that will run for you on Windows without needing them. I have never written a line of VBScript in my life till today so there may be other easier ways of doing this:

```
'###############################################################################
' File: process.vbs
' Author: Mark Setchell
'
' VBScript to process companies file.
'
' Use as follows:
' cscript /nologo process.vbs < file
' 
' Or, to save to an output file, use as follows:
' cscript /nologo process.vbs < file > results.txt
'###############################################################################
Dim rxp, inp
Set rxp = new RegExp
rxp.Global = True
rxp.Multiline = False
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   inp  = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()

   ' Regular expression to match any upper case letter
   rxp.Pattern="[A-Z]"

   ' If there are any letters on the input line
   if rxp.Test(inp) Then
      ' Replace multiple spaces with a single comma
      rxp.Pattern="  +"
      inp = rxp.Replace(inp, ",")
      ' Remove leading and trailing commas off line
      rxp.Pattern="^,|,$"
      WScript.StdOut.Write rxp.Replace(inp, "")
   Else
      ' Write a blank line since there was nothing on input line
      WScript.StdOut.WriteBlankLines(1)
   End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I rise to the challenge. I am not sure EXACTLY what you want for output, but I guess a CSV will be importable into any database. Here is what I have:

```
sed -E 's/[ ][ ]+/,/g' yourfile | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""}/^$/{print "\n"}{print $0}'
```

The "sed" part converts multiple spaces into commas to separate the fields and hopefully doesn't convert single spaces into commas. The "awk" part then sets the Output Record Separator to nothing so "awk" doesn't output any newlines and I can control them. The "^$" looks for empty lines and I introduce a newline into the output myself when I encounter that, else it just prints the input line. With the data you provide, the output looks like this:

```
SUNCOR ET AL MEDHAT 9-17-15-4,0416613,ALBERTA CROWN,753.3M,100/09-17-015-04W4/00,S,543.4M,W,167.6M,MEDICINE HAT,656.8M,DEV (NC),MEDICINE HAT,FISH SCALE ZONE,VERTICAL,NEW,PRODUCTION,GAS,SUNCOR ENERGY INC.,09-17-015-04W4,
CVE HOUSE 3-23-83-17,0416614,ALBERTA CROWN,536.17M,1AB/03-23-083-17W4/00,N,281.3M,E,686.8M,BONNYVILLE,283.7M,OV (C),HOUSE,MCMURRAY FM,VERTICAL,NEW,OIL SAND EVALUATION,CRUDE BITUMEN,CENOVUS ENERGY INC.,03-23-083-17W4,
CVE GRANOR 11-27-82-18,0416615,ALBERTA CROWN,554.69M,1AA/11-27-082-18W4/00,S,756.7M,E,677.6M,BONNYVILLE,409.2M,OV (C),GRANOR,GROSMONT FM,VERTICAL,NEW,OIL SAND EVALUATION,CRUDE BITUMEN,CENOVUS ENERGY INC.,11-27-082-18W4,
SUNCOR ET AL MEDHAT 4-17-15-4,0416616,ALBERTA CROWN,750.9M,100/04-17-015-04W4/00,N,320.1M,E,317.1M,MEDICINE HAT,646.4M,DEV (NC),MEDICINE HAT,FISH SCALE ZONE,VERTICAL,NEW,PRODUCTION,GAS,SUNCOR ENERGY INC.
```

I guess the trailing commas at line ends could be cleaned up with another

```
sed -e "s/,$//"
```

onto the end of the original pipeline if necessary.

I'll stop there because I have no idea if I am on the right track!

Comment: Hi Mark, I think you are on the right track yes. Output to csv is actually very useful as it allows me to convert each txt to a csv which I can check and then merge into one file.

Comment: Hi Mark, I now have sed and awk installed and the command seems to run without error's...but where would the output be?

Comment: I am guessing you are using Windows if you had to install awk and sed, correct? You need to change the word "yourfile" in the command I gave you into the name of the file where your data is. So, if your data is stored in a text file called "companies.txt", you will need to start a Command Prompt (MS-DOS window) and run the command I gave you like this: sed -E .... comapnies.txt | awk 'BEGIN....     The output should appear on your screen and scroll past quite fast. If that works, run the command again, but add "> results.txt" to the end to save the results in a file called "results.txt".

Comment: Apparently we aren't supposed to chat on here, so if you are stuck, just Email me on mark at thesetchells.com